# How to stop a sound with a button?

Tags: matlab, audio

I am new to Matlab. I want to play a sine through the sound function. Now i want to stop the sound by pressing a button on the keyboard. Is it possible? I thought about using "clear playsnd". But i am not sure.

```
fs=44100;   %Sample Frequency
 samples=1/fs;
 d=10;        %Duration
 t=0:samples:(d-samples); % time
 amp=linspace(0.0001,2,441000); %Increasing the amplitude

 input('Please press enter ')
 %Definition der Variable "Weiterlaufen" als true für die while schleife
 a = true; 
 while a

 disp(' ') 

   switch input('Chose 1 and press enter to play sound: ');
      case 1 %Generating sound with a frequency of 125 Hz          
          f = 125;
          s1 = sin(2*pi*f*t);
          y= amp.*s1;
          sound(y,fs);

   end     
end
```

Comment: `ctrl+c` would stop the sound. Apart from that I don't believe that there is a way as the duration of the sound depends upon the size of the signal that you give it.

Comment: @Suever Is it possible that the problem lies within `while true` loop? I can't see any way how `a` can be `false`.

Comment: @Crowley Yes that's part of the problem. The question is pretty unclear.

Comment: you cannot stop a sound played by `sound`. Instead, construct an `audioplayer` object and use its `play` and `stop` methods.

Comment: @Suever this part can be solved by `otherwise a=false` in the end of `switch` options.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late; but `clear sound` is a solution to this.